# How ? Joomla article html code, form post xml return hide

Tags: html, xml, forms, post, joomla1.5

I made a form in html (joomla article).
The user input is posted to a server where I can not change the return url.

What I want is: 
User fills out form and click submit. End of story (maybe a thank you page).
It does that now, but the page is loading for ever (maybe 10-20 sec) before it then returns a xml code with the status of the posted request - AND the server url, which I want to keep secret to the user.

So how do I allow the user to move on after the click, with out the waiting time - or how do I hide the status url in the browser, if the user must wait for the server xml response ?

I need to mention that I do not have full control over the html code in the joomla article.
Joomla inserts the html header forexample.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <form action="http://serverUrl" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="login" value="mylogin" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="mypass />
    Textbox to send:<br /> 
    <textarea style="width: 209px; height: 86px;" name="text" rows="4" cols="40">Insert text. </textarea><br /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="myfrom" /> <br />
    Text 3:<br /> 
    <textarea style="width: 209px; height: 30px;" name="text3" rows="4" cols="40">your text 3</textarea>
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" /> 
    <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
    </form>
```

I have found some related posts on stackoverflow, among other sites.
But the suggestions does not work - and I am not that much of a super shark in coding.

Comment: I'm slightly worried that you appear to be sending usernames and passwords in plain text over `POST`.

Comment: @Benedict: no choice. Speaking chinese to an african gets me nowhere. If the user pass is encrypted the server would need a key. I cant put a key on the server. Besides Post should be safe to use for operations like this - where GET is not.

Comment: No. POST is not safe to ever send passwords, as it can easily be intercepted. You need to look into using `SHA` to hash your passwords before they are sent, some information on that is available [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). **Passwords should NEVER be sent in plain text, no matter how.**

Comment: I will maybe take a look at it when above problem has been solved.

Comment: Benedict:
As I already explained: I do not have access to the server the username and password are sent to - so I can not salt or hash, nor both. Your comment is strictly noise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well - "BUMP".

I made a work around - it turned out that I could use java script in the html code.

I now have followning:
Open the joomla page in a new window.
and inserted this in the submit line:

```
    <input onclick="javascript: setTimeout(window.close, 400);" type="submit" value="SEND" /> <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
```

It lets the page timeout after 400 milisec, then it closes.
Hope it works in all browsers - only checked it in firefox so far.

It is now 100% what I wanted, but it does the job more or less.
No waiting time for the users after posting and the form is posted - some secrecy is maintained due to the relatively fast closure of the window/popup.

Comment: And it should have said: "and changed the submit line to this"